# Google Ads interrupt the app. Slow down fps

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I use `AdView mAdView` and the last updated libraries.

I placed the AdView into my layout (as shown in the examples):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Then I identify it and try to load a new ad in the `onCreate()` method:

```
AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But my layout has some animated objects. This animation is freezing (skipping some frames) while new ad is become visible.

We can't catch the same problem with the disabled Internet (it disables ads and not affect lags).

I'm trying to show the problem with my own record (GIF can't show that completely):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adH2Mn79O7w

How can I remove ads' lags and make the user experience better?

Comment: Need more information on what kind of Ad is loaded. {Video? Text? Image?)
Make sure you don't overlay.

Comment: @FungLAM you see it at the bottom of the second screen. It is Google's Ad. Default Ad - banner: 150x50. And what do you mean when you talking about "overlay"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue, which has been discussed many times on the net, is enough to search by the words "AdMob fps drop" and the like.

The root of the problem here, most likely, is that running AdMob requires significant resources, which is why the animation starts to stall. As one solution, you can show ads with some delay:

```
Handler handler = new Handler ();
handler.postDelayed (new Runnable () {
     @Override
     public void run () {
          AdRequest bannerRequest = new AdRequest.Builder (). Build ();
          mAdView.loadAd (bannerRequest);
     }
}, 2000);
```

You can make the delay not fixed, but bind it to user actions. For example, start downloading ads the moment after the user has stopped scrolling the screen.

Another solution is to disable graphics acceleration for ads by manipulating the LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE property.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(){
        runOnWebView(mAdView, new WebViewAction(){
            @Override
            public void run(WebView view){
                view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

For such a solution, it is necessary to implement the following interface:

```
private void runOnWebView (View view, WebViewAction action) {
    if (view instanceof WebView){
        action.run((WebView)view);
        return;
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)view;

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            runOnWebView(parent.getChildAt(i), action);
        }
    }
}

private interface WebViewAction{
    void run(WebView view);
}
```

Similarly, you can turn off the acceleration for some Activity:

```
<activity 
    android:hardwareAccelerated = "false"
    android:softwareAccelerated = "false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround which I also have in my apps is setting a `layertype`:

```
mAdView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

or

```
 mAdView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Comment: Lags are actually here.

Comment: I don't think so. It is not working. I have own answer. It helped me

Comment: @EgorRandomize but you added my solution in your answer!! I think you should give me correct sign :)

Comment: Sure! I actually don't know which part helped indeed.

Comment: view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
  view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

This part and I hope this was the main solution! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207933/discussion-between-jamil-hasnine-tamim-and-egor-randomize).

Answer (score 0):

I'd think, that the advertisments shouldn't be a `banner`, since that is a big advertisment, and that is slowing down the performance, as you should make it small. This also could cover things in your application, (if the advertisment is on `banner`).

Another thing is that you could not have ads, so that performance would be better. Try any of these. Ads most of the time have very good graphics and may slow down your application. :)

Comment: I've to say: ads has a fixed default size: it is really small: 150*50. Graphics? No. It is GIF I guess. `Banner` is the name for ads like this. I've seen it on the AdMob.

Comment: If you have a server, like Google, then  it'd be ok to use advertisments. If not, don't put ads, and have some other way of monotization.

Comment: I'm just can't understand what do you mean. Finally I got that you don't understand the question and AdMob. AdMob uses Google's servers, actually it is Google's subsidiary

Answer (score 0):

Place the ad view in a linear layout and implement ad listeners. In onAdLoaded() method of adListener add adView to your linear layout like linearLayout.addView(adView) and put your animation on linear layout. I hope it helps you.